# How to determine Spinner value at startup with Python kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a GUI with Python kivy.
I want to display a random value on the GUI at startup.

I thought that it should be done in the __init__ function, and tried the following code.

**test.py**

```
import random
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 300)
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

class TestWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        first = random.random()
        second = random.random()
        third = random.random()
        self.ids.spinner_test.values = [str(first),str(second),str(third)]

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'random value'

    def build(self):
        return TestWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
TestWidget:

<TestWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size:root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Spinner:
            id:spinner_test
            text: ""
            values: []

        Label:
            text: ""

        Label:
            text: ""

        Label:
            text: ""
```

However, the following error occurred and the GUI did not start. 
How can I fix the code?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'spinner_test'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the TestWidget constructor is used before .kv so the id "spinner_test" does not exist at that time.

Given this, a possible solution is to make that change a moment after showing the GUI:

```
# ...
from kivy.clock import Clock
# ...

class TestWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update)

    def update(self, *args):
        first = random.random()
        second = random.random()
        third = random.random()
        self.ids.spinner_test.values = [str(first), str(second), str(third)]

# ...
```

Another option is to create a ListProperty where the values are set and then make a binding with the "values" property of the Spinner:

```
TestWidget:

<TestWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size:root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Spinner:
            id:spinner_test
            text: ""
            values: root.values # <---

        Label:
            text: ""

        Label:
            text: ""

        Label:
            text: ""
```

```
# ...
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

# ...


class TestWidget(Widget):
    values = ListProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        first = random.random()
        second = random.random()
        third = random.random()
        self.values = [str(first), str(second), str(third)]

# ...
```